# Uppercase to Lowercase with Sed and character classes

Tags: class, replace, sed, character

I'd like to convert a string from upper to lower case. I know there are different ways of solving this problem, but I'd like to understand why this command doesn't work:

```
echo "aa" | sed 's/'[:upper:]'/'[:lower:]'/g'
```

Is it a wrong way to use the classes of characters?

Answer (score 6):

from lowercase to uppercase, you can use

```
echo "aW123bR" | sed -r 's/[a-z]+/\U&/g'
```

`tr` command is an interesting alternative

```
echo "aW123bR" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, the `y` command is used for mapping sets of characters:

```
sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/'
```

It requires a literal list of characters, not character classes.

Comment: But is not possible to use [:upper:] or [:lower:] to get a more elegant solution?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The `y` command only works with characters, not classes. You can't even write `y/A-Z/a-z/`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution with gawk :

```
[ ~]$ echo "HELLO"|awk '{print tolower($0)}'
hello
```